# Typescript JSON to interface dynamically

Tags: json, typescript

I'm pretty new to typescript and I want to turn the below JSON into an interface/type but the `user1` key is dynamic and could be something different but the JSON inside the of key will be the same.

```json
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "user1": {
       "firstName": "John",
       "lastName": "Smith",
       "age": 25
     }
  }
}
```

I have the below so far. Is it possible to turn the data into a map in the Root interface as this is how I would do it in golang.

```
export interface Root {
  code: number
  status: string
  data: Data
}

export interface Data {
    [key: string]: User
}

export interface User {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    age: number
}

export const sendRequest = (url: string): Root => {
  const [data,setData]=useState([]);
  const getData=()=>{
    fetch(url
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
    )
      .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        setData(myJson)
      });
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
}

const user = sendRequest(host + path) 

console.log(user.data?.[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use index signatures:

```
export interface Root {
    code: number
    status: string
    data: Data
}

export interface Data {
    [key: string]: User
}

export interface User {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    age: number
}
```

Comment: I think a generic Root would be more useful.

Comment: Hmmmmm well it was working but not sure what I did its not working any more getting the below error message
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined

data?.[0].aggregation

Comment: How are you using it?